# Simulate openni compatible camera

Tags: ros, openni, object-recognition, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And again, hi folks,

it seems that for built in `object recognition` an `openni` compatible camera is way to go. I don't have such a cam here at home but what I do have is a simulator that's capable of creating simulated captured image data (rgb and depth).

I could send that data to ROS. But I don't have a clue on how to convert that data in such a way that it will be interpreted by ROS as real image data coming from an `openni` compatible camera.

Any idea on how to do that, use simulated image/depth data for `openni` respectively object recognition?

Thanks again and again and again! You're a great community!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92976/simulate-openni-compatible-camera/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm no expert on the openni stack in ROS, so you may get better answers later.

First, determine which topics & message types your object recognition node needs. For my application, this is `/camera/rgb/image_color`, `/camera/depth_registered/points`, `/camera/depth_registered/camera_info`, `/camera/depth_registered/image`. I think some of the tabletop object detection applications only require the points. You probably don't need to simulate the whole set of nodelets that you'd get with `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`.

Next, convert the information you have from your simulator into `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` and/or `sensor_msgs/Image` messages. The best way to do it will depend on your incoming data format. If you have to send images, I find it easier to deal with cv::Mat as a data type and use cv_bridge to convert to a ROS message just before publishing.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-22**:
Okay, I have raw RGB8 image data available from the simulator. I send it to a ROS node via TCP which converts it to sensor_msgs/Image. I can see the image in RViz (it's upside down, but I'll deal with that later). I'll try to combine that with the object recognition stack and keep you informed. Thx!